# Can't see a MenuBar

Tags: java, jmenubar

the code that I wrote does not show the menubar, any idea what I should do?

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//What happens on close.
this.setSize(1100, 750);//Initial size of the frame.

menuBar = new MenuBar();

east = new EastPanel();
central = new CentralPanel();
south = new SouthPanel();

//Add the menu bar to the frame.
this.setJMenuBar(menuBar.getComposition()); 

//Frame's other components.
this.add(central.getCentralPanel());
//this.add(msBoard.getMessagesBoard(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.add(east.getEastPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
this.add(south.getSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//this.add(menuBar);
//Load the card images.
//cards = new CardImages();
//cards.loadCards();

//Initialize cardsPerPlayer list.
//cardsPerPlayer = new ArrayList<ImagePanel>();

this.setVisible(true);
```

where getComposition is

```
public JMenuBar getComposition(){
    return this.Composition;
}
```

and Composition is private JMenuBar

Answer (score 1):

Propably because You didint add anything to this `menubar`.

In eclipse when ive added menu bar (using builder) without any items i didint see it but after i add menu to menubar it will works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `MenuBar` is not enough. You should attach it to the current `JFrame` object.
Also make sure you're adding some menu items into it.

Example:

```
frame.setJMenuBar(theJMenuBar);
```